# tar command - compress without folders

Tags: bash, tar

I use a tar command like this:

```
tar -cf backupdb/db/2012/11/database.2012-11-25.tar.gz backupdb/db/2012/11/25/*.sql
```

But when I open the tar file I see a directory backupdb/db/2012/11/25 :/
How to modify the command to compress files backupdb/db/2012/11/25/*.sql but without parent directories.

I know the -C switcher in tar command, but I don't know how to use it to compress files with specify exptension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `-C` flag:

```
tar -C backupdb/db/2012/11/25/ -cf backupdb/db/2012/11/database.2012-11-25.tar.gz *.sql
```